# asp.net cannot convert type DataRowView to DbDataRecord

Tags: asp.net

working on asp.net with c#.
i have a dataset function.

The function is asigned to a datagrid datasource:

```
DataGrid2.DataSource = datasetfunction(parameter);
```

but when the databind is reached:

```
DataGrid2.DataBind();
```

it throws error: "cannot convert type System.Data.DataRowView to System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord"

One thing to note:  the same function was of type sqldatareader, but i needed to change to a dataset type. so in the function i converted the sqldatareader to datatable and then the datatable to a dataset. So then now i get this error.

How can i solve this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the [signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131(v=vs.71).aspx) of `datasetfunction`?

Comment: Check this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756355/how-can-i-convert-or-cast-a-dbdatarecord-into-a-datarow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756355/how-can-i-convert-or-cast-a-dbdatarecord-into-a-datarow

Comment: i saw the link Simio but i dont understand.......where should I edit my code?

Comment: Signature:.... `code public static DataSet datasetfunction(int intdr, DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {}`

Comment: any help is welcomed here. im really lost

Comment: i changed it back to  sqldatareader type and found a workaround. thanks!